# change a different div's class on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css

There's many examples of this but I can't find the right one for me - I believe mine is a more simple example.

I have as follows:

```
<li onmouseover="this.className='change-here2'" onmouseout="this.className='change-here'"> 
    <div class="change-here">
       Text Here
    </div>
</li>
```

The li element has a background image, and a hover effect that changes the background image.

Using **this**.className changes the li class, when what I want is to change the div below it's class.

Shouldn't I be able to modify **this** to div.change-here, or something similar? I don't know the syntax...

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: TimWolla's solution works brilliantly. Thank you all.

Comment: your example isn't of much help when the use-case isn't explained.. are you trying to use it for your upload photo, or something else?  It looks like you have css rules in place... so I'm at least still lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you use CSS only?

```
li .class { background-color: red; }
li:hover .class { background-color: green; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/zp2td/

Comment: Better than my solution :) ... though mine should still work.. upvote

Comment: @Silvertiger Nope. He wanted to change the class of the `div`, not the class of the `li`.

Comment: changed my answer to incorporate all the suggestions since it was a little more complex than just changing the current element div.

Comment: That works brilliantly. I was using inheritance classes like that too, not sure why I didn't think of it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something to the affect of $(this).children(':first').addClass('change-here'); for that?

Comment: OP never specified jQuery. Suggest it and give the OP a reason to use it.

Comment: Should have mentioned by javascript knowledge is virtually nill so I'm not sure how to implement that...

Comment: jQuery is just a JS file you import. It registers a ton of useful functions that make this sort of work a piece of cake. http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: as @Blender has noted, it's using jQuery... wishing we knew more about the project, but basically, you include the *.js lib from http://jquery.com/ in your html page, and then you can use the notation from above to add/remove the class.  Then again, dependent on the use-case, I think TimWolla may have a better alternative, unless you have some weird business logic you need to implement.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer to incorporate all the suggestions**

```
<style>
    .div_1 {
        color: #F00;
    }
    .div_2 {
        color: #0F0;
    }
</style>
<li onMouseOver="this.childNodes[0].className = 'div_1';" onMouseOut="this.childNodes[0].className = 'div_2';"> 
    <div class="div_1">
       Text Here
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: He wanted to change the class of the `div`, not the class of the `li`.

Comment: That works, but then the hover affect is only triggered by mousing over the DIV element, which is a small image, rather than the li element, which is much larger.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i=0, len=lis.length; i<len; i++){
    lis[i].onmouseover = function(){
        var firstDiv = this.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        firstDiv.className = 'change-here';
    };
    lis[i].onmouseout = function(){
        var firstDiv = this.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        firstDiv.className = '';
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zfTzE/).

The reason I'm taking this approach, rather than using the in-line `onmouseover` attribute, is to make it somewhat easier to adapt in the case of the requirements changing at a later date. Also, it's slightly less 'intrusive' this way, and leaves the html somewhat easier to read. It is, of course a personal preference, though.

It's worth noting that the CSS-approach, as mentioned by [TimWolla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917845/82548) is far more sensible than involving JavaScript.

Comment: I must confess to being curious as to the down-vote. Any ideas? (If I'm suggesting something *wrong* or *useless* then I'd love to know, so's I can amend my approach and adjust my approach for subsequent answers).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
this.childNodes[0].className = 'change-here';
```